# Can't get information that's inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to get information that's inside an array but can't, every time returns an undefined statement.

That's the array, it's inside the variable 'RESULTADO'

```js
debug   {"recordType":"customrecord5",
         "id":"1",
         "values":{
           "CUSTRECORD4.custrecord6":[{"value":"11",
                                       "text":"11 CP BUSINESS : Empresa Teste"}],
           "CUSTRECORD4.custrecord5":[{"value":"7",
                                       "text":"LASER"}]}}
```

Code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++){
    var valores = resultado[i];
    log.debug(valores);
    var dados = valores['value']; // NAO ESTOU CONSEGUINDO PERCORRER A VARIAVEL DADOS 
    log.debug(dados);
    for (var u = 0; u < dados.length; u++){
        valor = dados[u];
        log.debug(valor);
    }

}
```

I need to get the information that's inside the index 'value', but cant get in...

Comment: That is not an `array` you have an `object` there.

Comment: Please edit your question. Provide `resultado` structure or sample. In debug, values is an object not an array.

Comment: @bh4r4th I think that's the output from `log.debug(valores)`, so it's one element of the array.

Comment: You have a typo: `valores['value']` should be `valores['values']`

Comment: But `dados` is an object, not an array. Each property in this object contains an array of objects.

Comment: @Barmar good catch. Could be a typo. Alcantara wants values to be an array and structure shows an object. Which is not a good practice too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the data you have is not an Array, it is an Object.

Well, JS Objects are also known as "Associative Arrays" but they have much different behavior.
They are structured with "KVP" Key Value Pairs { KEY: VALUE }

To iterate over an object you have to use different type of loop like for/in loop.

```
let resultado = {
   "recordType": "customrecord5",
   "id": "1",
   "values": {
      "CUSTRECORD4.custrecord6": [{"value": "11", "text": "11 CP BUSINESS : Empresa 
       Teste"}],
      "CUSTRECORD4.custrecord5": [{"value": "7", "text": "LASER"}]
   }
};

for (let KEY in resultado) {

   console.log(KEY); // recordType, id, values
   console.log(resultado[KEY]); // customrecord5, 1, {...}
}
```

Or you can turn it into array

```
let resultadoArr = Object.entries(resultado);
console.log(resultadoArr);

// [ [ 'recordType', 'customrecord5' ],
//   [ 'id', '1' ],
//   [ 'values',
//     { 'CUSTRECORD4.custrecord6': [Object],
//       'CUSTRECORD4.custrecord5': [Object] } ] ]
```

And one more advice, use 'let' and 'const' instead of 'var'. It is the new standard nowadays.

I hope I have helped

Answer (score 1):

The name of the property is `values`, not `value`. And its value is an object, not an array, so you can't use `dados.length`; use a `for-in` loop to loop over the keys.

```
for (var i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++){
    var valores = resultado[i];
    log.debug(valores);
    var dados = valores.values;
    log.debug(dados);
    for (var u in dados){
        if (dados.hasOwnProperty(u)) {
            valor = dados[u];
            log.debug(valor);
        }
    }

}
```